package twemojis and euro coin
I'm using the package twemojis, particularly the coin symbol through command \twemojis{coin}. I wonder if a similar symbol in size, colour and shape can be created but with "1€" inside the coin instead of the Parthenon? With thanks.

welcome! can you provide the code for a minimal example which shows how to create the coin with the Parthenon?

Hi! No, I don't have any code for the Parthenon. That's what I want know, i.e. I would like to know how was conceived \twemojis{coin}...? Thanks.

the emojis are from Twitter. there is also a byo-twemojis for 'build your own'. did you look at that? https://www.ctan.org/pkg/byo-twemojis  repo for twemojis is at https://gitlab.com/rossel.jost/latex-twemojis. there is also a twemojis-extra which is not yet on ctan.
